Are there any popular methods or algorithms for finding when a velocity curve crosses over itself/loops around?
I've looked online and surprisingly couldn't find anything with a web search. This seems like a common problem that has to be solved for, especially for dynamical systems. I feel that there must be work done to solve this rather common problem.
I need this problem for a computer program that I'm writing, but I'm going to discuss the problem in a more idealized sense. The velocity curve that I'm discussing can be approximated in whatever way leads to the best algorithm, be it a discrete family of vectors, a collection of parametric curves that agree at points, or whatever approximation leads to a good algorithm.

Problem Statement:
Let $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ be some parametric (velocity) curve that may or may not loop back on itself. Are there any popular algorithms or methods for finding when the curve loops back or crosses itself?
That is, for any pair $(t, \gamma(t))$, how best can I determine if there exists some $t' \le t$ such that $\gamma(t) = \gamma(t')$?

I can always naively search backwards across the half-open interval $[0, t)$ and check for any such values, but the time complexity of this algorithm becomes $\approx O(n^2)$, which is unwanted, especially for longer and longer curves.
I've spent an embarrassing and irresponsible amount of time trying to solve this. I've tried evaluating curvature, integrations of curvature, and so forth, but alack! No success.
Are there any algorithms that exist that are more practical in terms of time or space complexity? What are some popular/good algorithms and approaches for solving this problem?

I have had success with an algorithm that I found in the Matlab File Exchange.The reference page is: Douglas Schwarz (2024). Fast and Robust Curve Intersections (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11837-fast-and-robust-curve-intersections), MATLAB Central File Exchange.

Assuming the curve is polygonal (as an approximation to the real curve), You can choose a segment and divide the plane in two by its line. Sort the other segments into three groups: those lying on one side, those lying on the other and those that cross. Investigate the latter for intersections of the segment itself. For the rest, you know that those on one side cannot intersect those on the other, and thus do not need to be tested. For each side, chose a segment  in it and use that segment to do a division of that side (both segments on that side and the crossers).

@CyeWaldman Thanks, although from documentation: "The check is to look at the smallest
% enclosing rectangles (with sides parallel to the axes) for each line segment
% pair and see if they overlap.  If they do then we have to compute t1 and t2
...
% then the line segments cannot cross.  In a typical application, this technique
% will eliminate most of the potential line segment pairs."
This would still be $\approx O(n^2)$ I think, although you can probably get his algorithm down to $O(n \log n)$ if you stick the bounding volumes in a k-tree.

@PaulSinclair Would this happen to be a named algorithm or part of a class of named algorithms with a documented time complexity or approximate time complexity?

It is just my thoughts on what would be a good approach. However, it is based on common concepts, so I do not doubt you could find fully developed algorithms that fit the plan. But, no, I do not have a reference for you.
